# MySQL query relation table join table or sub select

Tags: mysql

I'm new with mysql , i have 2 tables with 1 relation sid(field)

```
    tb_data

    sid | total 
    a   | 2         
    b   | 3         
    c   | 4         

    tb_ref

    sid | part
   ------------
    a   | x
    b   | x
    c   | y
```

How to create query so i will get all value  on `tb_data` when `tb_ref=x`, the output should be

```
a,2

b,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is you check it

```
       select s.sid,t.total from tb_data s,tb_ref t where t.part='x' and s.sid=t.sid;
```

if not work please comment me...:)

Comment: there is no total column for tb_ref

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
     `SELECT t1.* FROM tb_data AS t1, tb_ref AS t2 WHERE t2.sid = 'x' AND t1.sid = t2.sid`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT td.* FROM tb_data AS td, tb_ref AS tr WHERE tr.part = 'x';
```